# Is it possible to apply trigger on any table in information_schema?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to apply trigger on any table in information_schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that the tables in information_schema are really views.  This is mentioned [here](http://docs.sun.com/source/mysql-refman-5.0/information-schema.html).

According to MySQL, you can't make triggers on temp tables or views.  See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) for a discussion about that.

So, I'm going to say no based on that information.  I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong on this.

There is a discussion similar to what you are asking [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?101,296939,296939#msg-296939).

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to do accomplish a task I have mentioned here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,360049,360049#msg-360049

Please Throw Some Light

Comment: Saw your question there.  If I understand your scenario correctly, you are trying to get the TRIGGER to dynamically adjust to the fact you've renamed a column that is specifically mentioned in the TRIGGER's definition.  Of course, it doesn't do that automatically and the update fails because the TRIGGER is looking for the old column name and it has been renamed.
My advice would be to just keep things simple and if you need to modify the table's column name, modify the trigger's definition.  Someone smarter than me might have another approach.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Someone smarter is there --
Just kidding but I've been trying to do the same thing and the only obvious answer is to add an abstraction layer, unfortunately.

Simply put, instead of just SQL("ALTER TABLE ....") you will need to call a higher level function (written by yourself) in another language, like this:

->

```
modifytable( $old_table_structure,$new_table_structure){
 alter_table_base_table($old_table_structure,$new_table_structure);
 alter_table_history_table($old_table_structure,$new_table_structure); //just guessing   that's what I'm doing with it so thought it was the same for you
 alter_history_triggers($old_table_structure,$new_table_structure);
}
```

I really wanted to do this straight in the DBMS, but it seems like information_schema wasn't meant for that.

And of course, you'll want to have all that in one transaction, to make sure it doesn't explode ;)